# Coldfusion using javascript to show/hide a div block

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I'm programming in ColdFusion5 and trying to show/hide a div block of code based on the onchange call of a select statement.  I found similiar issues online, however I've had no luck using style.display or visibility.  With this code, I am able to get into the js function, the first alert fires off the value of the select selection, and I get a second alert inside the the if statement.  Once it hits the line to hide/show the div, it drops out. Any ideas?

**ColdFusion code (note: this code is in an iframe):**

```
<select name="select_Attendee_2" required="yes" onchange="parent.showHideGuestForm();">
        ...stuff...
    </select>
    <div id="GuestLayer1">
        ...more stuff...
    </div>
```

**Javascript (in external file):**

```
function showHideGuestForm()
{
    var iFrame = $($('#my_iframe').contents());
    alert(window.my_iframe.document.formAttendees.elements['select_Attendee_2'].value);

    if ((trim(window.my_iframe.document.formAttendees.elements['select_Attendee_2'].value)) == '')
        {
            alert("before none");
            window.my_iframe.document.formAttendees.getElementById('GuestLayer1').style.display = 'hidden';
            alert("after none");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("before block");
            window.my_iframe.document.formAttendees.getElementById('GuestLayer1').style.display = 'block';
            alert("after block");
        }
}
```

Comment: If you use Firefox/Firebug, do you see any undefined variable errors?

Comment: Firebug shows: TypeError: window.my_iframe.document.formAttendees.getElementById is not a function

Comment: You might be overscoping.  What if you tried it without the formAttendees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a problem with overscoping, removing the form name solved the problem:

```
window.my_iframe.document.getElementById('GuestLayer1').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

This was bugging me, so I tried it with html files.  It has nothing to do with ColdFusion.  Here is the relevent part of the page inside the iframe.

```
<p id="p2">This is page 2.</p>
<form id="myForm" action="Page2.html" method="post">
    <div id="div1">
        <p>This is in the div.</p>
    </div>

</form>
```

Here is the relevent part of  the parent page, including the javascript.

```
<p id="p1">hello</p>
<iframe id="myIframe" width="100" height="200" src="Page2.html"></iframe>
<p>
    <button id="theButton" value="a button" onclick="hideDiv()"></button>

</p>
<script>
    function hideDiv() {
        var iFrame = document.getElementById("myIframe");
        var theDiv = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("div1");
        theDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

</script>
```

This code works in Firefox.  I didn't try it in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I give jquery example to hide/show a div on checked (in toggle)

```
<!--jquery code -->
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<script language="jscript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#NewVendor").click(function(){
    $("#ebdiv").toggle();
});
});
</script>
<!--jquery code ends -->

<!-- cf part--->
 <input type="checkbox" name="NewVendor" id="NewVendor"  /> New Vendor

 <div id="ebdiv" >
<table  border="0" width="70%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="cartContentsDisplay">
<tr>
<td width="25%"><b>New Vendor </b></td> <td>:*</td><td align="left"><cfinput type="text" name="VendorName" id="VendorName" value="" size="30"  />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Address</b> </td> <td>:*</td><td align="left"><cfinput type="text" name="Address" id="Address" value="" size="30" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
<<!-- cf part ends--->
```

it is working on Chrome and did check in other browser.

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted. Using jquery is a good thought. However, the code above does not do what they asked, which is triggering an action from a select list inside an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code............

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showDiv() {
    if (document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
<div id="hiddenDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >
  WELCOME
</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```